# How can I reference particular cells in a dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner and this is my first project.. I searched for the answer but it still isn't clear.
I have imported a worksheet from excel using Pandas..

**Rabbit Class:

```
 Num  Behavior  Speaking  Listening

0                1         3         1          1

1                2         1         1          1

2                3         3         1          1

3                4         1         1          1

4                5         3         2          2

5                6         3         2          3

6                7         3         3          1

7                8         3         3          3

8                9         2         3          2
```

What I want to do is create if functions.. ex. if a student's behavior is a "1" I want it to print one string, else print a different string.  How can I reference a particular cell of the worksheet to set up such a function?  I tried: val = df.at(1, "Behavior") but that clearly isn't working..
Here is the code I have so far..

```
import os
import pandas as pd

from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

path = r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python\rabbit_class.xls"

print("Rabbit Class:")
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to find rows where `df.Behavior` is equal to 1. Use any of the following three methods.

```py
# Method-1
df[df["Behavior"]==1]
# Method-2
df.loc[df["Behavior"]==1]
# Method-3
df.query("Behavior==1")
```

Output:

```
   Num  Behavior  Speaking  Listening  LastColumn
0    0         1         3          1           1
```

> ## Note: Dummy Data
>
> Your sample data does not have a column header (the last one). So I named it `LastColumn` and read-in the data as a dataframe.

```py
# Dummy Data
s = """
Num  Behavior  Speaking  Listening LastColumn
0                1         3         1          1
1                2         1         1          1
2                3         3         1          1
3                4         1         1          1
4                5         3         2          2
5                6         3         2          3
6                7         3         3          1
7                8         3         3          3
8                9         2         3          2
"""
# Make Dataframe
ss = re.sub('\s+',',',s)
ss = ss[1:-1]
sa = np.array(ss.split(',')).reshape(-1,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(sa[0,:], sa[1:,].T)))
df = df.astype(int)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do

```
dff = df.loc[df['Behavior']==1]
if(not(dff.empty)):
    # do Something
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below example will help you

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\test_stackoverflow.xlsx")
print(df.columns)

def _filter(col, filter_):
    return df[df[col]==filter_]

print(_filter('Behavior', 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.  I finally figured out what I was trying to do using the following code:

```
i = 0
for i in df.index:
student_number = df["Student Number"][i]
print(student_number)
student_name = student_list[int(student_number) - 1]
behavior = df["Behavior"][i]
if behavior == 1:
    print("%s's behavior is good" % student_name)
elif behavior == 2:
    print ("%s's behavior is average." % student_name)
else:
    print ("%s's behavior is poor" % student_name)
speaking = df["Speaking"][i]
```